# Why is java util logger printing certain messages in German?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, java.util.logging, eclipse-mars

I have used java util logging for my application. I noticed that certain properties such as the month name and even certain log levels are getting printed in German.

```
Dez 10, 2015 8:50:26 AM com.kube.common.HidCommunication readFromHidDevice
SCHWERWIEGEND:  Time - Barcode Message read from the Device: 2015/12/10 08:50:26:992
```

Though I have specified the level as Level.SEVERE, why is it printing it as "SCHWERWIEGEND" in German? Please advice.

Comment: What is your `Locale.getDefault()`? (I'd assume German.) Try `java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US MyClass`. As for why, it's because German seems to be the default locale of your OS.

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot. Please put this as the answer to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to change the language of java.util.logging to English?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486841/java-how-to-change-the-language-of-java-util-logging-to-english)