# Java: How to change the language of java.util.logging to English?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have java.util.logging to print output to a file. It works fine. However, the messages contain chinese characters which correspond to the **log level** and the time the messages are logged.

How can I make it print english instead of chinese characters ?

This is what the current messages look like

```
11月 08, 2016 8:28:03 下午 mySamples.testing.TestingFile errorFunction
資訊: Exception: 123
```

Comment: you can use     Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); to change the log level languages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start your application by passing the language on the command-line to override the current default language of the OS.

```
java -Duser.language=en MyApplication
```

Comment: Is there a way that I override it permanently ? I am using Eclipse to compile and run the applcation.

Comment: You can define an environment variable called  `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en` to make it the default value for the JVM.

Comment: If you want to set it programmatically, you can put `System.setProperty("user.language", "en")` in a static block at the beginning of your main class (class containing the main method)

Comment: interesting blog post about it https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/logging_localized_message

Comment: Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "EN")); works for me (and System.setProperty does not).