# How to print month and time stamp in locale using log4j or logback

Tags: java, logging, logback, log4j2

I am able to print log information like log level(info,debug) and log month in locale using **java.util.logging.Logger**. Is it possible to bring same in log4j/logback?

Example:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LcTest.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.TAIWAN);
    logger.info("Hello");
}
```

Console Output:

> 十二月 03, 2017 4:41:15 下午 locale.LcTest main 資訊: Hello

Comment: Just edit the appender however you want in the config. If you don't know how to I suggest you to look at any already existing resource on log4j2.

Comment: Will this previous question and answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486841/java-how-to-change-the-language-of-java-util-logging-to-english